# Retrieving the current font definition of a tkinter.ttk.Label widget

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, ttk, ttkthemes

I wish to retrieve the font object currently assigned to an arbitrary `tkinter.ttk.Label` widget.

(To be more exact, I want to obtain the exact *configuration attributes* of the widget’s current `tkinter.font.Font` instance — `family`, `size`, `weight`, `slant`, `underline`, and `overstrike` — in order to programmatically define modified variants of the same base font.)

This is easy to do with a plain, unthemed `tkinter.Label`:

```
import tkinter.font

# Create root object
root = tkinter.Tk()

# Create label widget
label = tkinter.Label( root, text="Hello world!" )
label.pack()

# Get font name (key) from the widget
font_name = label['font']
print( " font_name:", repr(font_name) )

# Get Font instance and print attributes
font = tkinter.font.nametofont( font_name )
for key, value in font.config().items():
    print( f"{key:>10}: {repr(value)}" )

# Display the widget
root.mainloop()
```

The above program prints out the font details as follows:

```
 font_name: 'TkDefaultFont'
    family: 'sans-serif'
      size: 10
    weight: 'normal'
     slant: 'roman'
 underline: 0
overstrike: 0
```

However, if I change it to use a `tkinter.ttk.Label` instead of a `tkinter.Label`...

```
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.ttk

[...]

# Create label widget
label = tkinter.ttk.Label( root, text="Hello world!" )
label.pack()
```

...it no longer works. This is because the expression `label['font']` now returns an empty string instead of a valid Tkinter font name. The empty string gets assigned to `font_name` and then used in a `nametofont` function call, resulting to:

```
 font_name: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fonttest.py", line 14, in <module>
    font = tkinter.font.nametofont( font_name )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/font.py", line 23, in nametofont
    return Font(name=name, exists=True, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/font.py", line 87, in __init__
    raise tkinter._tkinter.TclError(
_tkinter.TclError: named font font1 does not already exist
```

If I change the program yet further and specify a named `ttk` theme by adding the following lines after the creation of the `root` object but before creating the `ttk.Label` widget...

```
# Set up a ttk theme
style = tkinter.ttk.Style()
style.theme_use( 'breeze' )
```

...I get a somewhat different result, but still no valid font name:

```
 font_name: <font object: 'Helvetica 10'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fonttest.py", line 20, in <module>
    font = tkinter.font.nametofont( font_name )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/font.py", line 23, in nametofont
    return Font(name=name, exists=True, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/font.py", line 87, in __init__
    raise tkinter._tkinter.TclError(
_tkinter.TclError: named font Helvetica 10 does not already exist
```

Note how `label['font']` no longer returned a string — empty or otherwise — but a “font object”.

---

Adding some more debug prints...

```
print( " font_name:", repr(font_name) )
print( "font_name.__class__:", font_name.__class__ )
print( "font_name.__str__():", repr(font_name.__str__()) )
print( "dir( font_name ):", dir( font_name ) )
print( "tkinter.font.names():", tkinter.font.names() )
```

...gives us this output:

```
 font_name: <font object: 'Helvetica 10'>
font_name.__class__: <class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>
font_name.__str__(): 'Helvetica 10'
dir( font_name ): ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'string', 'typename']
tkinter.font.names(): ('TkCaptionFont', 'TkSmallCaptionFont', 'TkTooltipFont', 'TkFixedFont', 'TkHeadingFont', 'TkMenuFont', 'TkIconFont', 'TkTextFont', 'TkDefaultFont')
```

It is not really a “font name”, and not an instance of `tkinter.font.Font` either, but an instance of the class `_tkinter.Tcl_Obj`. The `dir` output lists a member called `typename` so I added this line, too...

```
print( "font_name.typename:", repr(font_name.typename) )
```

...which yields:

```
font_name.typename: 'font'
```

---

To summarize: sometimes the themed `ttk` widgets return an empty string for their font, some other times they return a “font object”. The “font object”, if present, is *not* a `tkinter.font.Font` instance but a `_tkinter.Tcl_Obj` instance — apparently a Python wrapper for an internal TCL `font` object whose properties are inaccessible to Python code?

Since this curious `font` object *is* convertible to a string (`Helvetica 10`), it could *technically* be used as a Tkinter “font name” in a font lookup call. Alas, the string that the object holds or converts into is still not a registered “font name” (that `tkinter.font.names()` or`tkinter.font.nametofont( font_name )` would recognize) so the attributes of the underlying font remain inaccessible.

So, my question is: what is the *correct* way to programmatically obtain the current `tkinter.font.Font` instance (or the equivalent attribute details — `family`, `size`, `weight`, `slant`, `underline`, `overstrike`) of the font assigned to a `tkinter.ttk.Label` widget both when a theme has been explicitly set and when it has not been set?

My test environment in the above was Python 3.10.12 that comes standard with Kubuntu (Ubuntu) 22.04 LTS. The packages `python3-tk` (version 3.10.8-1~22.04) and `python3-ttkthemes` (version 3.2.2+git20220101+07e6509cc6bf-1) were manually installed from the standard Ubuntu repositories.

---

**Edit:** I initially assumed the`ttkthemes` package would just passively register more TTK themes for the `tkinter.ttk` “theme engine”.

Not so: the `ttkthemes` package actually provides custom `ThemedTk` and `ThemedStyle` classes (derivatives of `Tk` and `Style`), which its friendly manual [instructs to use](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) in place of the standard classes, for loading the bundled themes.

This means the explanation given above about loading the *Breeze* theme using `tkinter.ttk.Style().theme_use('breeze')` is not exactly correct, even though it technically works on Ubuntu; `ttkthemes.ThemedStyle().theme_use('breeze')` should be used instead. Thanks to [pippo1980](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77742878/6312612) for making me realize this. This does not invalidate the original question but may make fully answering it somewhat more specific to the `ttkthemes` package than I originally thought.

---

[Nordine Lotfi’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77742985/6312612) *almost* resolves the question.

However, even while the described method works with all of the “bult-in” `tkinter.ttk` themes, some of the additional `ttkthemes` themes still escape it.

I made another small test program to illustrate this remaining issue. It tries to resolve a `tkinter.ttk.Label` widget “font name” in each available theme:

```
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.ttk

try:
    from ttkthemes import ThemedTk, ThemedStyle
    root = ThemedTk()
    style = ThemedStyle()
    print( "Using ttkthemes.ThemedTk and ttkthemes.ThemedStyle." )
except ImportError:
    print( "Using standard tkinter.Tk and tkinter.ttk.Style." )
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    style = tkinter.ttk.Style()

label = tkinter.ttk.Label( root, text="Hello world!" )
label.pack()
label_style = label.winfo_class()

def print_status( status, theme_name, font_name ):
    print( f"[{status:^6}] {repr(theme_name):>12}: {repr(font_name)}" )

for theme_name in style.theme_names():
    style.theme_use( theme_name )
    # font_name = label['font']
    font_name = style.lookup( label_style, 'font' )
    try:
        font = tkinter.font.nametofont( font_name )        
        print_status( "OK", theme_name, font_name )
    except tkinter._tkinter.TclError as e:
        print_status( "FAIL", theme_name, font_name )

#root.mainloop()
```

When I only have the modules `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` available in the Python environment, this program produces the following output on an Ubuntu system:

```
Using standard tkinter.Tk and tkinter.ttk.Style.
[  OK  ]       'clam': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]        'alt': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]    'default': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]    'classic': 'TkDefaultFont'
```

If I install the `ttkthemes` package (`pip install ttkthemes` or `apt install python3-ttkthemes`) and run the program again, I can no longer resolve all the “font names” (`FAIL` indicates an exception happened when trying to look up the resolved font name with `nametofont`):

```
Using ttkthemes.ThemedTk and ttkthemes.ThemedStyle.
[  OK  ]     'ubuntu': 'TkDefaultFont'
[ FAIL ]     'breeze': 'Helvetica 10'
[  OK  ] 'scidpurple': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]      'black': 'TkDefaultFont'
[ FAIL ]       'smog': ''
[  OK  ]   'aquativo': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]        'arc': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]   'scidgrey': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ] 'clearlooks': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]   'scidblue': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]       'yaru': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]       'kroc': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]   'scidmint': 'TkDefaultFont'
[ FAIL ]      'itft1': ''
[  OK  ]   'scidsand': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]    'classic': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]        'alt': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]    'equilux': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]   'radiance': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]   'scidpink': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]  'winxpblue': 'TkDefaultFont'
[ FAIL ]       'blue': ''
[  OK  ]    'default': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]  'scidgreen': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]       'clam': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]    'plastik': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]     'adapta': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]   'elegance': 'TkDefaultFont'
[  OK  ]    'keramik': 'TkDefaultFont'
```

(Is there some silent fallback mechanism going on in the style engine which handles these invalid TTK font names? Are these “outlier” themes incorrectly defined?)

Comment: If a font object is returned, you don't need to call `nametofont()`.

Comment: HOW CAMES import tkinter.font imports tkinter too

Comment: Can you fall back to "TkDefaultFont" if the returned font name is an empty string?

Comment: @acw1668 I definitely can. What I’m trying to confirm is: does the themed widget do this internally in all the cases where the “font name” resolves to an empty string? And what about the Breeze theme’s `Helvetica 10` case, which `nametofont` does not recognize as a “font name”, either?

Comment: Try changing `font = tkinter.font.nametofont(font_name)` to `font = tkinter.font.Font(font=root.splitlist(font_name))`.

Comment: A call to `splitlist` appears to turn *Breeze*’s ["Helvetica 10" font spec](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes/blob/56a7bdcb5c86b88aef637ffd60549efa1bf92839/ttkthemes/png/breeze/breeze.tcl#L50) into a two-item tuple `('Helvetica', '10')`, which then yields (likely) the theme author-intended *Helvetica* approximation from `tkinter.font.Font` (family *Nimbus Sans*, size 10 in my environment.)

Whether the widget actually *uses* *Nimbus Sans*, size 10 for rendering text when this theme is loaded is then another question which would have to be confirmed separately by visual inspection.

Comment: A call to `splitlist`does not exactly seem to help with the themes whose “font name” resolves to an empty string, since this yields an empty tuple, which instantiates a `Font` with empty family (!) and size 0 (!).

Comment: When `splitlist` is used with themes whose “font name” for the widet is `TkDefaultFont`, it gets “split” into a single-item tuple `('TkDefaultFont',)` which somehow seems to yield the actual `TkDefaultFont` realization (`Font.actual()` config is the same). This is however a new instance/copy with a new “font name” (`font1` by default) and not the original `TkDefaultFont` instance already in the named fonts cache, so a bit wasteful.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using `tkinter.ttk.Style()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.ttk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tkinter.ttk.Label(root, text="Hello world!")
label.pack()

style = tkinter.ttk.Style()
widget_style = label.winfo_class()
print("Widget Style:", widget_style)

font_name = style.lookup(widget_style, 'font')
print("Font Name:", font_name)

font = tkinter.font.nametofont(font_name)
for key, value in font.config().items():
    print(f"{key:>10}: {repr(value)}")

root.mainloop()
```

Which prints on my end:

```
Widget Style: TLabel
Font Name: TkDefaultFont
    family: 'Segoe UI'
      size: 9
    weight: 'normal'
     slant: 'roman'
 underline: 0
overstrike: 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Resolving the TTK font name by the widget style class name _almost_ works — just not with all the themes that the package `ttkthemes` provides. I added some more sample code to the question to illustrate the remaining issue.

Comment: I think this is happening because of the way the theme is made in Tcl. For example, one of the ones that worked `elegance`: https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes/blob/master/ttkthemes/themes/elegance/elegance.tcl#L41 here you can see it set up the TkDefaultFont, but for other ones that failed like `blue`: https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes/blob/master/ttkthemes/themes/blue/blue.tcl it does no such thing @JukkaAho

Comment: @NordineLofti That seems to be the direct cause of this difference. Yet, even the themes that “fail” the font lookup test *do* get some “concrete” font set in the `ttk.Label` widget, by some logic, which would be nice to know, or be able to subject to programmatic introspection/reflection. For the sake of completeness, here’s where the *Breeze* theme gets its `Helvetica 10` font definition, which also makes the lookup fail: https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes/blob/56a7bdcb5c86b88aef637ffd60549efa1bf92839/ttkthemes/png/breeze/breeze.tcl#L50

Answer (score 1):

not sure my code is how it should be done, but googling around SO I figured out that there are ways to solve your question using `tkinter.font.Font` toghether with `tkinter.ttk.Style`  class ([tkinter.ttk.Style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style)) , see code below :

```
import tkinter.font

import tkinter.ttk

from tkinter.font import BOLD, Font 

# Create root object
root = tkinter.Tk()


# Set up a ttk theme
stylez = tkinter.ttk.Style()
# style.theme_use( 'breeze' )  ### not used see below


default_font_root = tkinter.font.nametofont(stylez.lookup(root , 'font')).actual()

print('default_font_root : ' , default_font_root)

print("default_font_root size : " , default_font_root['size'])

# Set up a ttk theme
print(stylez.theme_names())

stylez.theme_use(stylez.theme_names()[2])

#same of 
stylez.theme_use('default')

#create Font
fontz = Font(root , family = 'Ubuntu',  size = 64 , weight = BOLD , underline = 1)


stylez.configure('my.TLabel', font = fontz)


# Create label widget
label = tkinter.ttk.Label(root, text="Hello world!" , style = 'my.TLabel')

label.pack()


print(""""style.lookup("TLabel", "font" : """ , stylez.lookup("TLabel", "font"))                    
                       
print(""""style.lookup("my.TLabel", "font" : """ , stylez.lookup("my.TLabel", "font"))
                       


label_font = tkinter.font.nametofont(stylez.lookup(label['style'] , 'font')).actual()

label_font_name = tkinter.font.nametofont(stylez.lookup(label['style'] , 'font')).name

print('label_font : ' , label_font, label_font_name)


print("fontz['size'] : ", fontz['size'])

# Display the widget
root.mainloop() 


"""
this is used to get available Font families in your system :
    
    from tkinter import Tk, font


    root = Tk()

    for i in sorted(font.families()):
        
        
        print('\n',i)

"""
```

Comment: Thank you. This made me realize the `ttkthemes` package requires using its own derivatives of the `Tk` and `Style` classes (`ThemedTk` and `ThemedStyle`) to load the extra styles it provides, such as `breeze`. It does not just register new styles to `tkinter.ttk` and use it “as is” (even though at least on Ubuntu, loading the new themes is technically still possible with the standard `ttk.Style().theme_use()` function, or at least it does not error out on them). I edited this detail to the question.